# How to render GeoJSON tiles from Tilestream for polymaps?

Tags: geojson, tilemill, polymaps

Have been using polymaps successfully till now.

Need to generate GeoJSON tiles for Canada Provinces.

Found [Tilestream](https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream) and got it working with [Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/).

Is there a way I can make Tilestream hand out GeoJSON tiles for polymaps without Wax?

http://my_tilestream_server:8888/provinces/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.json

### EDIT

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Still trying to make either Tilestream / Tilemill or Tilestache work correctly.

Does anyone know where I can find a good shapefile for Canada and its Provinces (Canadian Fips code would be a bonus)?  Only ones I have found are not accurate at zoom levels greater than 8.

1 - Tilestream / Tilemill are great, but need a way to dynamically add additional data to the Hover.  Can't seem to find a way to do this without including it in the dbf.

2 - Installed Tilestache, but having problems converting data from shapefile to sql.  I think I am messing missing something in the conversion to sql.  Or is there a data source I can import that already has this info?

Comment: Have you tried tilestache http://tilestache.org/ ?

Comment: Trying to install it now as a fallback, but haven't worked with python before.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data too large to fit in a DBF, or is there another problem there? QGIS and OpenOffice can both help with joining more data into your datasource. That's really the best way to add data at this point, since you'll have it all in one place and have no additional AJAX delay in displaying interactivity.

You can also query for more data based on tooltip contents - by using jQuery's .live() function, or replacing the `wax.tooltip()` implementation with one that pulls more data.